# How to display user data on another page after taking input using Laravel Collective Forms & Resource Controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I'm trying to make a simple registration form using Laravel Collective Forms and I'm using Resource Controller to handle the data afterwards. What I want to do is display the user info on another page after he clicks submit, a more formatted/stylized page. Following is my form.blade.php:

```
<table>
    {!! Form::open(array("route"=>"form.store")) !!}
    <tr>
    <td>{!! Form::label('First Name',null,array('class' => 'labels')); !!}</td>
    <td>{!! Form::text('fname',null,array('class' => 'inputs')); !!}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>{!! Form::label('Last Name',null,array('class' => 'labels')); !!}</td>
    <td>{!! Form::text('lname',null,array('class' => 'inputs')); !!}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>{!! Form::label('Email',null,array('class' => 'labels')); !!}</td>
    <td>{!! Form::email('email',null,array('class' => 'inputs')); !!}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>{!! Form::label('Password',null,array('class' => 'labels')); !!}</td>
<td >{!! Form::password('password',array('class' => 'inputs')); !!}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>{!! Form::label('Country',null,array('class' => 'labels')); !!}</td>
    <td>{!! Form::select('country', ['pak' => 'Pakistan', 'aus' => 'Austrailia','china'=>'China'], null, ['class' => 'inputs','placeholder' => 'Choose Your Country']); !!}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>{!! Form::label('Gender',null,array('class' => 'labels1')); !!}</td>
    <td style="float: left;">{!! Form::label('Male'); !!}{!! Form::radio('male', 'Male'); !!}</td>
    <td style="float: left;padding-left: 50px;">{!! Form::label('Female'); !!}{!! Form::radio('female', 'Female'); !!}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>{!! Form::label('Date of Birth',null,array('class' => 'labels')); !!}</td>
    <td>{!! Form::date('dob', \Carbon\Carbon::now(),array('class' => 'inputs')); !!}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>{!! Form::submit('Register',array('class' => 'btns')); !!}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

And this is my Form Resource Controller:

```
class FormController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
       return view('welcome');
   }


public function create()
{
    return view('form');
}


   public function store(Request $request)
   {
       $fname = $request->input('fname');
       $lname = $request->input('lname');
       $email = $request->input('email');
       $password = $request->input('password');
       $gender1 = $request->input('male');
       $gender2 = $request->input('female');
       $dob = $request->input('dob');

       return view('result');

   }
```

After the user clicks submit, I want to echo out the data on another page called 'result.blade.php' but obviously, when I try to echo it out, it gives me the unknown variable error. I'm still pretty new to Laravel so I would love some guidance here, how do I echo this information out to a separate formatted page. I'm obviously doing something wrong so please, feel free to point it out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*when I try to echo it out, it gives me the unknown variable error*" - Well yeah, you're not passing anything to the view: `return view('result');`; where's the data? See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views for the numerous ways to handle this.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I can pass a variable in a similar way? Since It's giving me errors when I try doing `return view('result', ['$fname' => '$request->input("fname")']`

Comment: Did you read the link I posted? `return view('result', ['fname' => $fname]);` or `return view('result')->with(['fname' => $fname]);`, etc. The 2nd parameter of `view()` needs to be an array, associative arrays are `'key' => $value` pairs, don't wrap php variables in single quotes (`$variable`, not `'$variable'`), etc. This is basic PHP stuff... Please review proper syntax, and consider using an IDE that supports syntax hinting/highlighting.